# Swiper causing React Testing Library to fail test on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to run a render test on a Carousel component using [react testing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69249400/how-can-i-test-swiper-with-jest) and it appears Swiper is causing the following error:

> "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Carousel`."

Although the error is referencing a potential export issue on the Carousel module, I can verify that it's being exported and import properly.

In fact, the test does "pass" if I comment out all references to the Swiper components in the Carousel module.

I originally referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69249400/how-can-i-test-swiper-with-jest) where the top answer recommends mocking the swiper component(s) with jest mock, but unfortunately that didn't appear to work.

This is how my test is currently set up:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderTest } from '../../../utils';
import Carousel from '..';
import slides from '../../../testFixtures/carouselSlides';
import { Navigation, Pagination, A11y, Keyboard } from 'swiper';
// @ts-ignore - test
jest.mock('swiper/react', () => ({
  Swiper: ({ children }) => <div data-testid="Swiper-testId">{children}</div>,
  SwiperSlide: ({ children }) => (
    <div data-testid="SwiperSlide-testId">{children}</div>
  ),
}));

jest.mock('swiper', () => ({
  Navigation: props => null,
  Pagination: props => null,
  Scrollbar: props => null,
  A11y: props => null,
  Keyboard: props => null,
}));

renderTest({
  component: (
    <Carousel
      id="1"
      slides={slides}
      loopSlides={false}
    />
  ),
});
```

Here's the Carousel component, I've stripped some of the code to make it more readable for this post:

```
<div className="Container">
  <Swiper
    slidesPerView={1.05}
    loop={false}
    modules={[Navigation, Pagination, A11y, Keyboard]}
    navigation={{
      nextEl: `.next-${id}`,
      prevEl: `.prev-${id}`,
    }}
    pagination={{
      type: 'bullets',
      el: `.pagination-${id}`,
      clickable: true,
      bulletClass: 'bullet',
      bulletActiveClass: 'bullet-filled',
    }}
  >
    {slides}
  </Swiper>
</div>
```

Comment: While I don't have a solution, I can confirm I have the same issue, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll let you know if I solve it